# How to avoid changes in Android's UI, when keyboard is up or orientation is changed?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, android-softkeyboard, screen-orientation

I have a rather simple login page in my Android app, containing a header, username TextView, password TextView, Login button and an image footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <!-- Header  Starts -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <!-- Logo Start -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />
        <!-- Logo Ends -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Header Ends -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/footer" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Login Form -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
         >

        <!-- Application Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />

        <!-- Username Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <!-- Password Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <!-- Login button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Logon" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Login Form Ends -->

    </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

I have two problems I think are related:

1. When the keyboard is up, and I scroll down, I see that the image footer "hides" behind the login button, instead of staying below it.
2. The same is happening when the screen is oriented horizontally.

The things I've tried:

1. Setting in the activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, but I want to be able to scroll down when the keyboard appears, or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, or any other param for that matter.
2. Setting `marginBottom` in the button.

Neither worked.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the RelativeLayout capabilities:
I added an id to the LinearLayout of the "Login Form" named "form", and added this line to the ImageView that was hidden behind the button: android:layout_below="@+id/form".
Then made a few cosmetic changes.
Full code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <!-- Header  Starts -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Logo Start -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />
        <!-- Logo Ends -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Header Ends -->

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">

        <!-- Application Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <!-- Username Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <!-- Login button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Logon" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/form"

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/footer" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Footer Ends -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open your manifest.xml file .change in your activity tab .

```
<activity
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:name=".testActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

Comment: Did you also mean I should write something in the onConfigurationChanged method? Because I don't know what to change when the configuration is changed.. and only writing your suggestion doesn't work... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:configChanges="adjustPan" 
            android:name=".testActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

See about "android:windowSoftInputMode". Available modes [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)